# Django - How to filter by annotated value

Tags: python, django

Consider the following model. I'd like to filter objects based on the latest timestamp, which might be either `created_at` or `updated_at`. For some reason, the `filter` function does not recognise the annotated field and I'm having hard time finding the appropriate code examples to do this simple thing.

The error message is "Cannot resolve keyword 'timestamp' into field.".

How would you retrieve the Example objects within 7 days, based on newer date.

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest
from django.utils import timezone


class Example(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    @property
    def recently_updated(self):
        return Event.objects
            .annotate(timestamp=Greatest('created_at', 'updated_at'))
            .filter(timestamp__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7))
            .order_by('-timestamp')
```

Django 1.11

Comment: Don't know why your query failed it looks valid and runs for me on Django 1.11.20. But why not set updated_at to `auto_now=True` then you can easily query the updated_at field alone.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)`, this way when record is inserted for the first time updated_at and created_at will be same, so, you can just run the query on updated_at:

```
Event.objects.filter(updated_at__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)).order_by('-timestamp')
```